# How can I get a section of the data present in the format shown below?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, microsoft-excel-2013

I have the following columns of data:

```
Month   Mat Plant
Jan      x   p
Jan      y   q
Feb      x   p
Feb      z   r
Mar      x   p 
Mar      z   s
Apr      y   q
Apr      z   s
```

Then in a separate section of the sheet or another sheet, once I select a specific month in a cell, I want the following data for that month:

```
Month:  Apr

Mat     Plant
y        q
z        s
```

I tried to use `vlookup` but that works only to retrieve one row of data.

Edit 1:

Did as [Andi Mohr](https://superuser.com/users/151054/andi-mohr) suggested and got the results as expected:

```
Count of Mat        Month
Mat Plant   Apr
y   q        1
z   s        1
```

One issue with this though:

The combination of `Mat = y` and `Plant = q` has already occurred in Jan, so I want to be able to see that. If I remove the filter, then I can see it:

```
Count of Mat        Month           
Mat Plant   Jan Feb Mar Apr
x   p        1  1   1   
y   q        1          1
z   r           1       
    s               1   1
```

Is there any way I can get the following view:

```
Count of Mat        Month       
    Mat Plant   Jan Mar Apr
    y   q       1       1
    z   s            1  1
```

The count of materials should be 1 for the selected month and any previous month that has a 1 should also show up.

Any suggestion appreciated!

Edit 2:

The solution for the above issue would be to create the pivot table and then set filters for individual columns for each month. Then for the month of April, filter only the "1"s.

Comment: Have a read of this: http://chandoo.org/wp/2009/08/19/excel-pivot-tables-tutorial/. Set month as a filter, mat and plant as row labels, layout as tabular and remove all subtotals.

Comment: @AndiMohr : Took your suggestion , but there is one issue and I have updated it in the question. Could you provide a suggestion for that?

Comment: I've added a complete answer for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a PivotTable.

Click within your data, then select **Insert > PivotTable**. Add your *mat* and *plant* columns as `Row labels`, then add a count of months into values to show how often each combination has occurred.

You'll need to change your PivotTable layout to Tabular by selecting **PivotTable Tools Design > Report Layout > Show in Tabular Form.**, then right-click each row subtotal and remove them. That should give you something that looks like this:

[image]

Now if you only want to show records where there has been a match in April, then you'll need to add a new column to your orginal data with a formula. This will give you a way to filter out rows you aren't interested in.

In column D (in this example data), add a column called *HasAprSales*. Enter this formula in D2 and copy down:

```
=COUNTIFS($C$2:$C$9,"Apr",$A$2:$A$9,A2,$B$2:$B$9,B2)
```

This formula counts how many other rows exist for this combination of *mat* and *plant* for April. 1's signify there is a match, 0`s signify there is not.

You will need to edit this to match the relevant criteria in your data - the parameters in `COUNTIFS` follow this pattern:

```
=COUNTIFS(  rangetocheck1   --- your month column
           ,criteria1       --- the month you want to filter on, eg Apr
           ,rangetocheck2   --- your first column, eg Mat
           ,criteria2       --- the cell ref of Mat for this current row
           ,rangetocheck3   --- your second column, eg Plant
           ,criteria3       --- the cell ref of Plant for this current row
          )
```

Click on your PivotTable, then select **PivotTable Tools Analyse > Change Data Source** and alter your range to add in the new column. Now add the new *HasAprSales* as a filter to your PivotTable and select 1 to only show rows for April. That should give you something like this:

[image]

That's it!